# Ubuntu 22.10 disabled sound

Tags: sound, 22.04, hdmi, 22.10

I had Ubuntu 22.04 on my Asus PC and it was working great.
Paid to upgrade to Ubuntu Pro, thought I could update/upgrade to Ubuntu 22.10 to see what it looked like.

Sound quit working immediately. I get a message during boot that some AE thing cannot be found, but it scrolls past too fast to even screen shot it.
Tired to reinstall Ubuntu 22.04, since it worked, and I have all my files saved to cloud.

Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kaveri HDMI/DP Audio Controller
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Kaveri HDMI/DP Audio Controller
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 48
Memory at feb64000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [58] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Root Port
DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
Flags: fast devsel

00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Root Port
Flags: fast devsel

00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Root Port
Flags: fast devsel

Didn't help. Sound through the HDMI cable that allows my Sanyo monitor/tv to display video doesn't work at all.

Thought it might be the sound card in the PC, but I plugged in an external speaker (USB) and it works fine.

[lspci list image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Psjum.png)

[had to take a video and capture a single image of the error I get with every boot since I installed 22.10 and had to reinstall 22.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RBl7.png)

WTH does it mean by 'nobody cared' ???

[so this is what my 'sound' screen shows now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4JQC.png)

Comment: Ubuntu Pro is only relevant to LTS releases. Ubuntu 22.10 is an interim release so it doesn't really make sense to use this release if you're paying for a Ubuntu Pro subscription.  All versions of Ubuntu are free. Ubuntu Pro is also free to individuals. FYI, it you just want to try another release just to see what it looks like, you can run them as a live session from bootable installation media without affecting your installed system.

Comment: Search for sound and post a screenshot of Sound menu (Settings)

Comment: I really appreciate that information about 22.10 not being necessary.
but your answer doesn't help resolve my problem with sound not working. I've tried everything that I've found in answers and now even my external speakers only make static noises.